# Keep only a few digits of decimal part

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv, numeric-data

I have a file whose contents look like this.

```
2,0,-1.8433679676403103,0.001474487996447893
3,1,0.873903837905657,0.6927701848899038
1,1,-1.700947426133768,1.5546514434152598
```

CSV with four columns whose third and last columns are floats.

I want to get rid of the whole part of the numbers (including the sign) and keep only the three first digits of the decimal part so that the above sample would become

```
2,0,843,001
3,1,873,692
1,1,700,554
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried already? I would recommend you read up on SED, AWK, and other text processing commands to see what they are capable of.

Comment: @JeffSchaller The signs are included in the whole part. I made it explicit, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F[,.] '{print $1","$2","substr($4,1,3)","substr($6,1,3)}' file
```

Where `-F` used to set the `FS` values to comma `,` and dot `.`

`substr` will print the 3 digits required after the dot.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's/-\{,1\}[0-9]*\.\([0-9]\{,3\}\)[0-9]*/\1/g' file
```

This looks for strings starting with an optional `-` followed by any number of digits followed by a period, followed by any number of digits out of which it will pick the first three.

Another way is to replace `[0-9]` with `[[:digit:]]` as

```
sed 's/-\{,1\}[[:digit:]]*\.\([[:digit:]]\{,3\}\)[[:digit:]]*/\1/g' file
```

Answer (score 1):

awk? Why not python?

```
import csv
filename = <yourfilenamehere>

for line in list(csv.reader(open(filename, 'r'))):
    extra = [str(int((abs(float(num)) % 1) * 1000)).zfill(3) for num in line[2:]]
    print(*(line[:2] + extra), sep=',')
```

Comment: Because this is Unix.SE.

Comment: Python runs in *nix systems.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/(^|,)[^\.][^,]*\.(...)[^,]*/\1\2/g' infile
```

Comment: **_note**: I give it to you to find out how does it works as a practice._

Answer (score 1):

```
$ perl -lne 'print join " ", /\.\K(...)/g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried by below awk method

command

```
awk -F "," 'OFS=","{print $1,$2,substr($3,4,3),substr($4,3,3) filename
```

output

```
2,0,843,001
3,1,739,692
1,1,700,554
```

Comment: It seems like there's some code missing? there's an unbalanced single quote and open curly brace.